# UITableViewController in UIViewController

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

Hello how to load UITableViewController in UIViewController.
Like in this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9S114beUwPM at 3:55.
I can't really get how he do it.

---

I'm sorry, rephrase:
I have TableViewController.xib with Table View and MainViewController.xib with View. How to add table from TableViewController.xib to MainViewController.xib View. Like in this video at 3:55.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any since. Please rephrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't watch the video.  You should use either a UITableViewController or a UIViewController with a UITableView.

A UITableViewController is specifically for managing view that is entirely a table and without much customization.

Both UITableViewControllers and UIViewController with a UITableView should implement the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate.